# Uncaught Reference Error xyz is not defined when trying to pass parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am currently trying to pass parameters to set the state of the current size selected depending on which option the user is currently on, so i setup a function as well as a parameter that whenever onSelect is triggered it passes the variable of the size but for some reason im getting that my function is not defined, im guessing its my syntax but i cant seem to figure it out, here is my current code:

```
const updateSize = userSize = () => {
      setSize(userSize);
      console.log(userSize);
    }
```

```
<select className="buttons form-control  mb-2">
                <option onSelect={updateSize("Small")}>Small</option>
                <option onSelect={updateSize("Medium")}>Medium</option>
                <option onSelect={updateSize("Large")}>Large</option>
              </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was because my function was inside another function without me noticing thus outside the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `const updateSize = userSize = () => {` make it `const updateSize = (userSize) => {`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting event listeners on individual options, set it on the `<select>` tag itself. Then get the text of the option selected and use it in tour code.

HTML

```
<select onchange="updateSize()" className="buttons form-control  mb-2" id="select">
     <option>Small</option>
     <option>Medium</option>
     <option>Large</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
<script>
     function updateSize() {
         let select = document.getElementById('select');
         let text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
         console.log(text)
     }
</script>
```

Text value can be Small, Medium or Large depending on what option was selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give parameter to a const function use below method.

```
<select className="buttons form-control  mb-2">
     <option onSelect={()=>updateSize("Small")}>Small</option>
     <option onSelect={()=>updateSize("Medium")}>Medium</option>
     <option onSelect={()=>updateSize("Large")}>Large</option>
</select>
```

Also for your updateSize function. keep the parameters inside the ().

```
const updateSize = (userSize) => {
  setSize(userSize);
  console.log(userSize);
}
```

Comment: This resolved the error but its acting as if the function updateSize() is not being called at all as its not setting the size or logging the userSize after i select the various sizes.